# Local storage is not deleting in firefox

Tags: privacy, firefox

I have Firefox 64 and I'm logged in a website that uses local storage instead of cookies to maintain the session. When I disable the DOM storage in about:config the website logs me out; But when I clear my browser history and check every box and restart my browser I'm still logged in! This means that clearing history and everything does not clear my local storage. How can i clear local storage? Is this a security bug in Firefox since clear history function should delete every private data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a security bug, rather it is a feature of [Local Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Local_and_session_storage) (which is designed to be persistent through restarts)

It can be cleared (or edited) by the user.  If you press `[F12]` Firefox will bring up the developer bar.  In the tab marked `Storage` is the sub section `Local Storage` where individual pieces of data can be deleted out of Local Storage at will

[image: Local Storage in FF]